# Saying “next to it/them”?

Tags: grammaire, indications-de-lieu

I was wondering how you would say “next to it/them”, as I am confused whether to use “*en*” in place of “*de*”, or “*de + lui/elle/eux/elles*” or even another construction: “next to” translates as “*à côté de*”.

Normally, in phrases that use *de*, you can replace it with *en* to mean “of/about... it/them” instead:

> J'ai peur **du chien** (I am afraid **of the dog**)
>   J'**en** ai peur (I am afraid **of it**)

However, with “*à côté de*”, I am struggling to see if you can use “*en*” here, or “*de lui/elle/eux/elles*”. Take the following:

> Le canapé est assez grand, et à côté du canapé il y a une télévision
>   *The sofa is quite big, and next to the sofa there is a television*

The problem with the above sentence is that using “next to the sofa” twice sounds ridiculous. As a result, I was wondering how to say “next to it”, so that the English could be rephrased to:

> *The sofa is quite big, and next to it there is a television*

I have two ideas, but am not sure whether either are correct (the second, using “*en*” sounds wrong in my opinion, though)

> Le canapé est assez grand, et à côté de lui¹ il y a une télévision
>   Le canapé est assez grand, et en à côté il y a une télévision

—
<sup>1. “*lui*” being because *canapé* is masculine.</sup>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, as you mentionned Canapé is masculine:

Le canapé est **grand** .

As for your question "et en à côté" does not make any grammatical sense.

Your  first instinct (and sentence) is grammatically correct,

> Le canapé est plutôt grand et à côté de lui il y a une télévision.

Because the only other item  mentionned in the sentence is the canapé and that "television" comes immediately after you don't even need to use any pronoun.

> Le canapé est plutôt grand et à côté il y a une télévision.

Though, as a native speaker, I'd say something more like

> Le canapé est plutôt grand, et il y a une télévision juste à côté.

Bringing "television" even closer to "canapé" leaves no doubt as to what the television is next to.

Answer (score 1):

*En* can only replace *de* + noun, not *de* + pronoun. In addition, it always follows a subject and precedes a verb - it can't follow a preposition.

For example,

*Il a acheté deux stylos - Il en a acheté deux.

Voulez-vous encore de vin ? - Merci, j'en ai assez.*